# I am no getting default date in my text field when I am clicking on done button of my date picker

Tags: ios6

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

```
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;


txtSelectNiche.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];

[txtSelectNiche setInputView:(UIView*)[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
```

txtSelectNiche.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                    [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

```
txtSelectNiche.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```